# Nuxt / Vue 2 override input value after change

Tags: html, vue.js, input, nuxt.js

I'm trying to create an input that converts the user's pressed keys to the last single upper-cased character (if the user types 'a' -> 'A', 'abc' -> 'C').

This is my code:

```
<template>
  <b-form-input
    ref="firstNameInitial"
    v-model="firstNameInitial"
  />
</template>

<script>
export default {
  firstNameInitial: {
    get () {
      return this.$store.state.certificateAdd.firstNameInitial
    },
    async set (val) {
      const newValue = StringUtils.convertToNameInitial(val)
      this.$store.commit('certificateAdd/setFirstNameInitial', newValue)

      // Tried this as well
      this.$refs.firstNameInitial.$el.value = newValue
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

This works fine if I type distinct letters, but if I type "aa" the input will show "Aa" since the getter isn't recomputed (vuex  still holds the same data: "A").

Even if I trick getter by refencing some dummy local data that gets incremented in the setter the component will not re-render because the `value` prop is not changed; but the underlining HTML input's value will always update even if Vue doesn't step in to change it.

I've even tried manipulating the DOM directly but that doesn't work either.

Any ideas on how this behaviour could be implemented.

Answer (score 0):

You're not supposed to use a mutation since it is synchronous. You should use a vuex action because of the way DOM will handle the updates. If you have it as an action, I think it may work fine.

If it does not work, maybe try both: `await this.$nextTick()` and then `action` (in this order).

Comment: The 2 suggestions didn't work but it pointed me to the right direction. Manually changing `this.$refs.firstNameInitial.$el.value = newValue` in the `$nextTick` does the trick.

Comment: @sheitan I'm glad my answer helped somehow.